# Multiple files output in fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, node-modules, fluent-ffmpeg

Is it possible to add multiple files as input to [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/blob/b6b6ef35d3c09d6dc71a23ceb1fc25bccb7acb1f/README.md) and get output for all provided files..?

**Edit 1:**

```
var commonPath = __dirname + '/path/to/file/'; 

ffmpeg() 
  .input(commonPath + 'file1.mp4')  
  .output(commonPath + 'newFile1.avi')
  .toFormat('avi')  
  .input(commonPath + 'file2.mp4')  
  .output(commonPath + 'newFile2.avi')
  .toFormat('avi')
  .on('error',function(err){
    console.log(err);
  })  
  .run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you go through the docs of `fluent-ffmpeg`, it's specified there that you can add multiple inputs and outputs using `.input()` and `.output()`.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply.... i have edited my answer. I tried code mentioned in the question but it writes the file2.mp4 to all the output files. Do you have any idea regarding this problem...?